# Django how best to perform api request for large jobs

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I need some direction as to how to achieve the following functionality using Django.

I want my application to enable multiple users to submit jobs to make calls to an API.

Each user job will require multiple API calls and will store the results in a db or a file.

Each user should be able to submit multiple jobs.

In case of some failure such as network blocked or API not returning results I want the application to pause for a while and then resume completing that job.

Basically want the application to pickup from where it was left off.

Any ideas as to how I could implement this solution or any technologies such as celery I should be looking at or even if you can suggest an opensource project where I can learn how to perform this would be a great help.

Comment: Do you want the users to know about the task status or just give them a signal the job is processing? And What do you mean by "pause" your application?

Comment: i want them to know the task status

Comment: You can use retry for celery, inside the celery task you can catch Exception and `self.retry()` and if you want to retry after a minute you can use `self.retry(countdown=60)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) and [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).
This post might be helpful.
https://medium.com/@ffreitasalves/executing-time-consuming-tasks-asynchronously-with-django-and-celery-8578eebab356